# Generate a Content Drilldown report with weeks in columns

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'm trying to create a report in Google Analytics, drilling into Content Drilldown.

Figure there are 200 second level page-path-levels I'm working with. Right now, if I select a time period, say last 12-months, then drill into Content Drilldown, I see my ~200 domains/directories in the left column, followed by columns for pageviews, unique pagesviews, agv time on page, bounce rate and exit %.  However, I want to see all of 2018, with columns breakout out week by week.

For the moment, I only care about unique pageviews.

The ONLY way I can see to do this right now is to run the report for week period, export to excel, then do it over and over 52 times to get a year.

Is there a way to run this report, but only ONCE, with unique pageview total showing week by week in columns?  I would have 52 columns and 200 rows.

A perfectly fine alternative would be to generate a report with the path-level & day (or week) concatenated in column A, with column B having the unique pageviews.  A report like this would be 2 columns, with 10,400 rows (200 x 52).  We could clean up this raw data in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick "Week of Year" as your secondary dimension. Make sure you set the rows to match the number of results and export to excel.
[image]